# I just want to know how to define the following predicate

Tags: prolog

Using the predicate  in prolog, how to define the predicate cutlast(L1,L2) which is true if L2 is L1 with the last element removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
cutlast([X],[]):-!.
cutlast([X|XS],[X|Y]):-cutlast(XS,Y).
```

Please, let me know if you have any question. :)

Comment: Can I know how to define the cutlast(L1,L2) with the conc(L1,L2,L3) predicate ?

Comment: @Nuwanthi Amend your question to be clear. If it needs to refer to `conc`, then it's obviously homework.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I know how to define the cutlast(L1,L2) with the conc(L1,L2,L3) predicate ?

Assuming `conc` is `append` then:

```
cutlast(L1, L2) :-
    conc(L2, [_], L1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're `conc/3` predicate is a home-brew version of [`append/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3), then:

```
cutlast( Xs, Ys ) :- conc(L2,[_],L1) .
```